# How to increase font size of shortcut toolbar in texstudio?

Tags: texstudio

I am using TexStudio but my shortcuts toolbar are appearing in small font. How to increase the font size of toolbar or shortcut bar

Comment: Aren't the answers here the better? So the other question should be closed instead of this one?

Answer (score 6):

Go to the options / configure TexStudio, then tick "advanced options" on the bottom left and go to the menu "GUI scaling". Play around with the values.

Comment: this does not change the font of the top menu bar, which is the main thing I need to increase.

Comment: @Echeban: Do you mean the bar which reads "File, Edit, Idefix, ..."? I think this has to be changed in the settings of your operation system.

Comment: Operating system? No, it is easy. I asked the question separately. Later I found the answer, so I answered my own question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513871/how-to-increase-font-size-of-top-menu-bar-file-edit-idefix-in-texstudio

Answer (score 0):

Go to the options -> Configure TexStudio -> Editor -> Font Size/Font Family....whatever you wish to change!!!

Hope it helps.[image: This screen will open up]

Comment: this changes only the editor font size, which is different than what the OP asked for