# How to increase font size of top menu bar (File Edit Idefix ...) in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

How can I increase font size of top menu bar (the one that shows File Edit Idefix ...) in TexStudio. I cannot use a mouse. I am using a touch screen with a capacitive pen. It is difficult to hit the correct item with the font being small. Reducing the screen resolution would enlarge it, but everything becomes fuzzy. I am am working at the recommended resolution for the screen 1920x1080 on a 21" Planar touch screen. I know how to enlarge the icons, that is not my problem. My problem is the menu bar at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Menu: Options > Configure Texstudio> General > Font Size

Comment: This is not the correct answer

Comment: Apologies, yes it is the correct answer. You need to restart Texstudio for it work